# Angular watch the url when it changes to a different website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to watch when the url changes (not with $locationChangeStart or something like this).

What I want is when the url changes from let us say "google.com => githib.com".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for `beforeunload` if you want - `window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {};` but you only know the user is leaving. You don't know where they're going, and you can't run any javascript on the place they land (same-source policy).

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted since I don't want to run code on their site but have a confirm leave for dirty information on my page